# How to make a transparent/wallpaper-showing Flutter app

Tags: android, dart, flutter, android-wallpaper

Basically, I'm trying for fun to write a launcher using Flutter, and one thing I'm stuck on is the home screen. I'm trying to make it so that you can see *through* the app and through to the wallpaper. I changed my `AndroidManifest.xml` like so:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTop"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar"  <!-- I changed this line -->
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection"
          android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

and put this in my `main.dart`:

```
return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Launcher',
  theme: new ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,  // <-- this line
  ),
  home: new HomeScreen(),
);
```

but it *still* doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transparent flutter background is possible now (July 2019).

The Android issue is being discussed [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28844)

**How to do it:**

- [This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28844#issuecomment-478939888) comment gives a detailed explanation.

Some working **Android** demo apps that are transparent:

- A transparent app that shows the device wallpaper [GitHub repo](https://github.com/phanirithvij/invisible_flutter)
- A transparent app that displays itself on top of other apps. [GitHub repo](https://github.com/NMateu/flutter_transparent_app/)

The iOS issue is [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21808)

A [comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21808#issuecomment-493609075) suggests that it's possible to have a transparent background on iOS.

It can be achieved by adding the following line to the ViewController.

```
flutterViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
```

And to set `flutterViewController.isViewOpaque = false`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've run into a bug in the Flutter Engine, which is tracked by https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9627.  At time of writing that bug has identified that the Flutter Engine (the c++ parts of Flutter) by default fills the whole FlutterView region with black on Android before letting the Dart code draw.